# How to save a aspx page content type in server side in the form of HTML page and print this HTML from client side

Tags: asp.net, html, printing

I have a  Table with header and footer but it does not support browser compatability.

So, I want to save this table in the form of HTML in server side and print it in client side 
with out print preview but headers and footers must be there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no legitimate way to bypass the print dialog and immediately output to a printer. I've heard of hacks in the past, but hopefully those security holes have long since been closed. Can you imagine if every malicious website you stumbled across could print the bible to your home printer?

Use CSS to create a printer-friendly layout of the table and page, and use javascript `window.print();` to bring up the user's print dialog so they can choose to print or not.